# How to change the highlight color of focused views for all views of my app?

Tags: android, kotlin

The color used to highlight the focused views for my app is too dull. What must I change in my app theme to use a different color. My app's theme is a derivative of `Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar`

I tried changing `android:colorFocusedHighlight` but nothing happens. Can someone explain why?

edit:I have figured it out. Changing `android:colorFocusedHighlight` will change the highlight focus color of simple android views. For material views you must change the ripple color instead.